# Python Class Stack Frame Limitations

Tags: python, class, stack-frame

If I have a class of the following format:

```
class TestClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 0

  def getNewObject(self):
    return TestClass()
```

Is there a limitation to the amount of times I can call the function?  For example:

```
obj = TestClass()
obj.getNewObject().getNewObject()
```

Is there a limitation to how many times I can call `getNewObject()` on the return value of `getNewObject()`?  If so what factors affect this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt it. One reason that makes me doubt it is that if we have this function:

```
def test(obj):
    obj.getNewObject().getNewObject().getNewObject()
```

And we [disassemble it](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
import dis
dis.dis(test)
```

We get this:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (obj)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (getNewObject)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (getNewObject)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 LOAD_ATTR                0 (getNewObject)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             21 POP_TOP             
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

That's just repetitions of [`LOAD_ATTR`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_ATTR) followed by [`CALL_FUNCTION`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION). I can't imagine that that would require much memory or other resources to manage. As such, there is probably no limit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recursion limit in Python (adjustable), but that is unrelated. Each call is made after the previous call has completed, so they're all called from the same level of the stack frame (i.e. from your user code). Now, you might hit a line-length limit or something, especially for an interactive Python shell.

Comment: i assume your mean the [recursion limit](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit), i also think it won't trigger that, yet it's good to point out that python does have limitation on stack frames

Comment: Oh, right. It's just there to detect infinite recursions. I forgot about that.